# Chained logical operator on asigment to functional programming

Tags: javascript, node.js, logical-operators

I'm trying to handle several options to fill a variable content in a cleanest way.

The simpliest case would be:

```js
const value = foo.bar || 'Default';
```

When a want to add a condition, I normally do like:

```js
const value = foo.bar || (n > 10 ? n : 'Default');
```

Which could be refactored to:

```js
const value = foo.bar || (n > 10 && n) || 'Default';
```

my doubt is when there are several stages, can it be solved by replicating this way or with the classical conditional

**Option A** (logical operator)

```js
const value = foo.bar
  || (n > 10 && n)
  || (n > 0 && 0)
  || 'Default';
```

**Option B** (with ternary conditional)

```js
const value = foo.bar
  || (n > 10 && n)
  || (n > 0 ? 0 : 'Default');
```

**Option C** (classic conditional)

```js
let value;
if(foo.bar) {
  value = foo.bar;
} else if(n > 10) {
  value = n;
} else if(n > 0) {
  value = 0;
} else {
  value = 'Default';
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to replicate it and see how it reacts?

Comment: You forgot switch/case, what is the question btw?)

Comment: The question is what is the cleanest way, if the option A, which I selected is or not a good practice of clean code.

Comment: I wouldn't say *any* of these is the "cleanest" way. A Maybe/Optional or probably an Either is going to be a better way for handling this using FP. Perhaps even [`cond`  from Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#cond). All the chained complex operations are hard to maintain and reason about.

Comment: The goal of this is to avoid the use of `let`, what is the option C, with a readable solution and without the use of third libraries.
Switch/case is not an option because doesn't work with complex conditions.

Comment: Use an IIFE for more complex cases but abstract from calling it: `const expr = f => f()` and use it like `const value = expr(() => {if ("bar" in foo) return foo.bar); else if (n > 10) ...})`. You can even utilize default arguments to make the data flow more obvious `expr((bar = foo.bar) => ...)`.

Comment: @NikitaMazur This code doesn't switch on anything, so you shouldn't use `switch` here

Comment: @IvenMarquardt Not sure why you think `expr` is cleaner than a simple common IIFE?

Comment: `youNameIt(() => ...)` has less sintactic noise / is more descriptive than `(() => ...) ()` In my opinion. Lack of let expressions is the actual shortcoming though.

Comment: @Bergi, `let value;

switch(true) {
 case(foo.bar):
    value = foo.bar;
    break;
  case(n > 10):
    value = n;
    break
  case(n > 0):
    value = 0;
    break;
  default:
    value = 'default'
    break
}`

Comment: @NikitaMazur Don't do that, `switch(true)` is just a overly verbose `if`/`else` chain.

Comment: @Bergi, okay, I will not do this again(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not abuse logical `&&` and `||` operators as conditionals. `(n > 0 && 0) || 'Default'` does not do what you expect, it always evaluates to `'Default'` due to the falsiness of `0`.

That leaves only the ternary conditional operator

```
const value = foo.bar
  ? foo.bar
  : n > 10
    ? n
    : n > 0
      ? 0
      : 'Default';
```

or the equivalent conditional statements

```
let value;
if (foo.bar) {
  value = foo.bar;
} else if (n > 10) {
  value = n;
} else if (n > 0) {
  value = 0;
} else {
  value = 'Default';
}
```

(`foo.bar || …` *does* work here, but I'd avoid it for visual consistency in this particular situation).

---

Another alternative, just for completeness, is an IIFE; so that you can still initialise a constant with an expression, but without nested conditional operators:

```
const value = (() => {
  if (foo.bar) return foo.bar;
  if (n > 10) return n;
  if (n > 0) return 0;
  return 'Default';
})();
```

Comment: The idea started with the ESlint I have configured, which validates the use of nested ternary conditionals as an error. That's why I didn't consider your first response as an option. I see the IIFE a good choice.

Comment: @GabrielRodríguezFlores Tbh I would just disable that eslint rule. With proper indentation, there is nothing about nested conditional operators that is confusing or unclear.

Comment: I agree with you, I am using the eslint recommendations together with the airbnb style and that is one of the preset rules. I was just wondering which way was cleaner.